# scrolling content issue onclick jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, frontend

I have a problem with scrolling you can see this website
http://client-acumenadagency.com/zois/index.html

When you scroll on index and than scroll on about us, this section goes up and show some area from bottom's content area but I do not wana show. I need full screen content area. i attached a screen short and hope you can understand.

I also have problem when i do this again and again than it hides my navigation bar from top so how can i fix this issue?

This is jQuery code what i am using

```
$(function() {
  // Stick the #nav to the top of the window
  var nav = $('.top-navigation');
  var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
  var isFixed = false;
  var $w = $(window);
  $w.scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
    var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
    if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
        nav.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0,
            left: nav.offset().left,
            width: nav.width()
        });
        isFixed = true;
    }
    else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed)
    {
        nav.css({
            position: 'static'
        });
        isFixed = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry i was not able to attach image but you guys can see when you will click on about us or our story link

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem on Chrome. Maybe it's a browser issue?

Comment: @rnevius this is same issue on all browsers even in Chrome